# Selecting values from Array

Tags: javascript

I have an array.

```
var array = [0,1,2,4]; 
var index;
```

Now i have four buttons. I may click on any button at random order, i need the index value to be updated as 0 for the first button clicked, 1 for the second button, 2 for the fourth button and 3 for the third button.

Comment: lol.. does this question sound weird

Comment: I didn't see a question which is why I was snarking.. but others seem to have figured it out so there you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html:

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:SetIndex(this)" value="one" />
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:SetIndex(this)" value="two" />
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:SetIndex(this)" value="three" />
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:SetIndex(this)" value="four" />
```

JavaScript:

```
var array = [0,1,2,4]; 
var index = 0;

function SetIndex(obj)
{
    // check if index is out of range and it might be useful
    // to see if this button already has an index assigned
    if (index < array.length && isNaN(obj.index))
    {
        obj.title = array[index]; // hover to see index...
        obj.index = array[index];
        index++;
    }
}
```

---

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/eS4qy/

Comment: Nice. Now ehr, what shall we do with it? Btw, you could have removed the `javascript:` part from the paste:P

Answer (score 1):

is this is what you want:

```
<button onclick="index=0">1</button>
<button onclick="index=1">2</button>
<button onclick="index=2">3</button>
<button onclick="index=3">4</button>
```

?

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:setIndex(0)" value="one" />
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:setIndex(1)" value="two" />
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:setIndex(2)" value="three" />
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:setIndex(3)" value="four" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var index = 0;

    function setIndex(i) {
       index = i;
    }
</script>
```